# How to know if a Delta ticket is refundable?

Tags: bookings, refunds, delta-air-lines, fare-class

I believe I booked a fully refundable ticket with Delta, but now I want to be sure.  How can I check?  My "Itinerary" available on their website under "My Trips" does not mention refundability at all.  My "Receipt" (also from the Delta website) has just the boilerplate "This ticket is non-refundable unless issued at a fully refundable fare. Any change to your itinerary may require payment of a change fee and increased fare."  The email confirmation they sent me does at least say "RFNDABLE/CHNGS PERMITTED", but I have no idea how to check if there is a fee associated with refunding (which would make it sound to me like it shouldn't really be called "fully refundable", but that's beside the point).  The booking class is Q, in case refundability can be determined by that.  The "fare construction" is NYC DL PAR1015.00QK6H40M2 DL NYC1015.00QK6H40M2 NUC2030.00END ROE1.00 XF JFK4.5

Comment: Have you called Delta to ask?

Comment: No (it seems silly to wait on hold for what should be trivial to answer just by looking at my ticket).  Even if I had, I would probably still ask here (I certainly wouldn't bet my life on getting the correct answer out of an airline phone representative).

Comment: When discussing refunds/credits with airlines over the phone, they never seem to know whether a given refund will go through or a given credit will be valid to purchase a given ticket until they actually click "refund" or "purchase" and see what happens.

Comment: I know you are looking for a way to determine that you bought what you thought you bought.  But in a practical sense does it actually matter?  Because you have your ticket now and what costs you will encounter in the future are already decided.  I can see it only as mattering if you wanted to argue with a Delta representative who disagreed with your opinion of the ticket conditions.  But then Delta would be decoding the same thing as you are asking here.

Comment: @PeterM: It's been less than 24 hours since I bought the ticket, so I can still cancel for free if I do it right now.  But I'd like to hang onto the ticket for longer and retain the choice to cancel it for free.

Comment: @JohnPardon I had thought about that option, but was running out of space.  However given the time constraint I think your best bet is then to call Delta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the fare basis code is `QK6H40M2` (you can see it in the "fare construction").

You can use a site such as [Expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/) to look up fare rules. This is part of the premium subscription, but you can get a 5 days free trial.

Go to fare information, enter your origin/destination (NYC/PAR), your dates of travel, and the fare basis code, and it'll show you the details for that fare. You can then ask for the fare rules, which are a long of rules which follow a number of conventions which sometimes make them quite hard to read for the uninitiated (because they are either generated automatically or used automatically, or both).

The full rules are (answer continues after this short interruption):

```
RULE APPLICATION AND OTHER CONDITIONS      NOTE - THE FOLLOWING TEXT IS INFORMATIONAL AND NOT
   VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
   MAIN CABIN FARES
   APPLICATION
    CLASS OF SERVICE
     THESE FARES APPLY FOR ECONOMY CLASS SERVICE.
    CAPACITY LIMITATIONS
     THE CARRIER SHALL LIMIT THE NUMBER OF PASSENGERS
      CARRIED ON ANY ONE FLIGHT AT FARES GOVERNED BY
      THIS RULE AND SUCH FARES WILL NOT NECESSARILY BE
      AVAILABLE ON ALL FLIGHTS. THE NUMBER OF SEATS,
      WHICH THE CARRIER SHALL MAKE AVAILABLE ON A GIVEN
      FLIGHT, WILL BE DETERMINED BY THE CARRIERS BEST
      JUDGEMENT.
ELIGIBILITY    NO ELIGIBILITY REQUIREMENTS APPLY.
DAY/TIME       OUTBOUND -
     PERMITTED SUN THROUGH WED ON EACH TRANSATLANTIC
     SECTOR.
   INBOUND -
     PERMITTED TUE THROUGH FRI ON EACH TRANSATLANTIC
     SECTOR.
SEASONALITY    OUTBOUND -
     PERMITTED 14SEP21 THROUGH 23OCT21 OR 18NOV21 THROUGH
     20NOV21 OR 15DEC21 THROUGH 17DEC21 OR 08APR22
     THROUGH 06MAY22 OR 04SEP22 THROUGH 22OCT22 OR
     17NOV22 THROUGH 19NOV22 OR 14DEC22 THROUGH 16DEC22
     FOR EACH TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR. SEASON IS BASED ON
     TRIP DATE.
   INBOUND -
     PERMITTED 14SEP21 THROUGH 30OCT21 OR 27NOV21 THROUGH
     29NOV21 OR 29DEC21 THROUGH 08JAN22 OR 08APR22
     THROUGH 13MAY22 OR 11SEP22 THROUGH 29OCT22 OR
     26NOV22 THROUGH 28NOV22 OR 28DEC22 THROUGH 07JAN23
     FOR EACH TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR. SEASON IS BASED ON
     TRIP DATE.
FLIGHT APPLICATION     THE FARE COMPONENT MUST NOT INCLUDE TRAVEL FROM/TO/VIA
   BELARUS.
   AND
   THE FARE COMPONENT MUST NOT BE ON
       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
           ANY KL FLIGHT OPERATED BY EI
           ANY AF FLIGHT OPERATED BY TO
           ANY DL FLIGHT OPERATED BY OK.
   AND
   THE FARE COMPONENT MUST BE ON
       ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
           ANY DL FLIGHT
           ANY AF FLIGHT
           ANY KL FLIGHT OPERATED BY KL
           ANY VS FLIGHT OPERATED BY VS
           ANY A5 FLIGHT
           ANY HA FLIGHT.
ADVANCE RESERVATIONS/TICKETING     CONFIRMED RESERVATIONS FOR ALL SECTORS ARE REQUIRED AT
   LEAST 14 DAYS BEFORE DEPARTURE.
   TICKETING MUST BE COMPLETED WITHIN 72 HOURS AFTER
   RESERVATIONS ARE MADE OR AT LEAST 14 DAYS BEFORE
   DEPARTURE WHICHEVER IS EARLIER.
MINIMUM STAY       TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE
   NO EARLIER THAN 12 HOURS AFTER ARRIVAL AT THE
   TURNAROUND.
MAXIMUM STAY       TRAVEL FROM LAST STOPOVER MUST COMMENCE NO LATER THAN
   12 MONTHS AFTER DEPARTURE FROM FARE ORIGIN.
STOPOVERS      UNLIMITED STOPOVERS PERMITTED ON THE PRICING UNIT AT
   USD 800.00 EACH.
TRANSFERS      2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
     ANY COMBINATION OF THE FOLLOWING -
      2 ONLINE ON DL
        IN UNITED STATES IN EACH DIRECTION.
   AND - 2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN DL AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
              CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN AF AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
              CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN KL AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
              CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN WS AND AF/DL/KL IN CANADA IN EACH
              DIRECTION
              BETWEEN AF AND AF IN CANADA IN EACH
              DIRECTION
   AND - 1 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN AF/DL/KL AND A5/AF IN FRANCE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
              BETWEEN AF/DL/KL AND AF/W2 IN FRANCE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
   AND - 2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
              BETWEEN DL AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
              BETWEEN AF AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
              BETWEEN KL AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
              BETWEEN VS AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
              DIRECTION
   AND - 1 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
           ANY COMBINATION OF THE FOLLOWING -
            1 INTERLINE INCLUDING DL
              IN HAWAII IN EACH DIRECTION.
         FARE BREAK SURFACE SECTORS NOT PERMITTED AND
         EMBEDDED SURFACE SECTORS PERMITTED ON THE FARE
         COMPONENT.
COMBINATIONS        DOUBLE OPEN JAWS NOT PERMITTED.
   END-ON-END
     END-ON-END COMBINATIONS PERMITTED. VALIDATE ALL FARE
     COMBINATIONS.
     PROVIDED -
       COMBINATIONS ARE FOR CARRIER 7H/9K IN ANY RULE IN
       TARIFF
       CPR     - BETWEEN THE UNITED STATES-CANADA
       DFR     - WITHIN THE UNITED STATES
       VPCR    - BETWEEN PUERTO RICO/VIRGIN
       ISLANDS-CANADA
       VPDR    - BETWEEN PUERTO RICO/VIRGIN ISLANDS-THE
       USA.
   OPEN JAWS/ROUND TRIPS/CIRCLE TRIPS
     FARES MAY BE COMBINED ON A HALF ROUND TRIP BASIS
     -TO FORM SINGLE OPEN JAWS
      MILEAGE OF THE OPEN SEGMENT MUST BE EQUAL/LESS THAN
      MILEAGE OF THE SHORTEST FLOWN FARE COMPONENT.
     -TO FORM ROUND TRIPS
     -TO FORM CIRCLE TRIPS EXCEPT FOR AROUND-THE-WORLD
      FARES.
     PROVIDED -
       COMBINATIONS ARE WITH ANY FARE FOR CARRIER DL/AF/
       KL/AZ/VS IN ANY RULE IN TARIFF
       IPRA    - BETWEEN USA/CA-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
       IPRAI   - BETWEEN THE USA/CANADA-AREA 2/3 VIA ATL
       IPRSAA2 - BETWEEN THE WESTERN HEMISPHERE-AREA 2
       VIA ATL
       IPRSAA3 - SOUTH ATLANTIC/CENTRAL/SOUTH AMERICA/
       MEXICO/CARIBBEAN/GREENLAND/ST PIERRE ET MIQUELON -
       AREA 3.
       COMBINATIONS ARE WITH ANY FARE FOR CARRIER DL/AF/
       KL/AZ/VS IN RULE 2222/4444 IN TARIFF
       ATDLR   - BETWEEN AREA 1-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
       OR RULE 2222/4444 IN TARIFF
       TAPVR   - BETWEEN AREA 1-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
       OR ANY RULE IN TARIFF
       FBRINPV - BETWEEN USA/CA-AREA 1/2/3.
   NOTE - THE CITY PAIRS BELOW ARE CONSIDERED THE SAME
          POINT -
          BUR-LGB  BUR-SNA  BWI-WAS  FLL-MIA  LAX-BUR
          LAX-LGB  LAX-ONT  LAX-SNA  LGB-SNA  NYC-EWR
          OAK-SFO  OAK-SJC  ONT-BUR  ONT-LGB  ONT-SNA
          SFO-SJC
BLACKOUT DATES     NO BLACKOUT DATES APPLY.
SURCHARGES     FARE RULE
   IF INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2.
     THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
     DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
   THE PROVISIONS BELOW APPLY ONLY AS FOLLOWS -
   WHEN TICKETS ARE SOLD IN CHINA.
     ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
       MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 400.00 PER
       DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
       ANY PASSENGER.
 
   GENERAL RULE - APPLY UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED
   IF INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2.
     THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
     DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
   THE PROVISIONS BELOW APPLY ONLY AS FOLLOWS -
   TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AF.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AM.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AZ.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR DJ.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KE.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KL.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KQ.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR ME.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR OA.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR OK.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR TN.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VA.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VN.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VT.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR PS.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VS.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR 9U.
   OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR 9W.
     THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
     DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          YR FEE MAY APPLY
     AND - ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
       MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 6.75 PER
       DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
       ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA AMS.
       AND - MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 7.00 PER
             DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
             FARE PER ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA ROM.
   MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 320.00 PER
   DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER ANY
   PASSENGER.
     AND - ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
       MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 6.75 PER
       DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
       ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA AMS.
       AND - MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 7.00 PER
             DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
             FARE PER ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA ROM.
ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL     ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL NOT REQUIRED.
TRAVEL RESTRICTIONS    NO TRAVEL DATE RESTRICTIONS APPLY.
SALES RESTRICTIONS     TICKETS MAY NOT BE SOLD IN VENEZUELA/CUBA/ZIMBABWE/
   CAMEROON/CHAD/CONGO BRAZZAVILLE/GABON.
   TICKETS MAY ONLY BE SOLD IN AREA 1/AREA 2/AREA 3.
PENALTIES    *SPECIAL EMERGENCY RULES
 *SUBJECT TO CHANGE AT ANYTIME
 
   ORIGINATING AREA 1 -
   FOR TICKETING ON/BEFORE 30APR21/FOR TRAVEL ON/AFTER
   01MAR20 AND ON/BEFORE 31DEC22
     IF TRAVEL ON THIS FARE COMPONENT MUST COMMENCE BY
     MIDNIGHT ON 31DEC22.
     CANCELLATIONS
     
       CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED FOR CANCEL/NO-SHOW.
     
     CHANGES
     
       CHANGES PERMITTED.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
          SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
          RULE 22 REROUTING
   ORIGINATING EUROPE -
   FOR TICKETING ON/BEFORE 30APR21/FOR TRAVEL ON/AFTER
   01MAR20 AND ON/BEFORE 31DEC22
     IF TRAVEL ON THIS FARE COMPONENT MUST COMMENCE BY
     MIDNIGHT ON 31DEC22.
     CHANGES
     
       CHANGES PERMITTED.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
          SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
          RULE 22 REROUTING
   GENERAL RULE - APPLY UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED
   CANCELLATIONS
   
     CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED.
   
   CHANGES
   
     CHANGES PERMITTED.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          ----TICKET VALIDITY----
          TICKET IS VALID FOR 1 YEAR FROM THE ORIGINAL DATE
          OF ISSUANCE AND TRAVEL MUST COMMENCE WITHIN THIS
          VALIDITY PERIOD. ONCE TRAVEL HAS COMMENCED THEN
          ALL TRAVEL MUST BE COMPLETED WITHIN 1 YEAR FROM
          THE DATE ON WHICH TRAVEL COMMENCED.
          IF A TICKET IS EXCHANGED OR REISSUED -
               1. A WHOLLY UNUSED TICKET MUST BE
               EXCHANGED WITHIN THE ORIGINAL VALIDITY
               PERIOD OF 1 YEAR AND WILL BE GIVEN A NEW
               TICKET ISSUE DATE BASED ON THE DATE OF
               EXCHANGE.
               2. IF TRAVEL HAS COMMENCED THEN THE
               TICKET MUST BE REISSUED AND ALL TRAVEL
               COMPLETED WITHIN 1 YEAR FROM THE DATE ON
               WHICH TRAVEL COMMENCED.
          .
          -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
          SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
          RULE 22 REROUTING
HIP/MILEAGE EXCEPTIONS     NO HIP OR MILEAGE EXCEPTIONS APPLY.
TICKET ENDORSEMENTS    THE ORIGINAL AND THE REISSUED TICKET MUST BE ANNOTATED
   - RFNDABLE - AND - CHNGS PERMITTED - IN THE
   ENDORSEMENT BOX.
CHILDREN DISCOUNTS     CNN/ACCOMPANIED CHILD PSGR 2-11 - CHARGE 100 PERCENT
     OF THE FARE.
         TICKET DESIGNATOR - CH AND PERCENT APPLIED.
     MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
       COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
   OR - INS/INFANT WITH A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2 - CHARGE 100
          PERCENT OF THE FARE.
              TICKET DESIGNATOR - CH AND PERCENT APPLIED.
          MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
            COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
   OR - INF/INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2 - CHARGE 10
          PERCENT OF THE FARE.
              TICKET DESIGNATOR - IN AND PERCENT APPLIED.
          MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
            COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          THE AGE LIMITS REFERRED TO IN THIS RULE
          SHALL BE THOSE IN EFFECT ON THE DATE OF
          COMMENCEMENT OF TRAVEL.  EXCEPTION- INFANTS WHO
          REACH THEIR 2ND BIRTHDAY DURING THEIR TRAVEL WILL
          BE REQUIRED TO OCCUPY A SEAT ON THE OUBOUND AND
          INBOUND FLIGHTS.  THE CHILDS FARE MUST BE APPLIED
          FOR THE WHOLE JOURNEY.
   OR - UNN/UNACCOMPANIED CHILD PSGR 5-14 - CHARGE 100
          PERCENT OF THE FARE.
              TICKET DESIGNATOR - UM AND PERCENT APPLIED.
         NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          UNACCOMPANIED CHILDREN UNDER 5 YEARS OF AGE WILL
          NOT BE ACCEPTED FOR CARRIAGE UNDER ANY CONDITIONS.
          UNACCOMPANIED CHILDREN AGES 5 THROUGH 7 MAY TRAVEL
          ON NON-STOP FLIGHTS ONLY AND MAY NOT CONNECT TO
          OTHER AIRLINES.
          CHILDREN AGES 8 THROUGH 14 MAY TRAVEL
          UNACCOMPANIED ON DELTAS NON-STOP OR CONNECTING
          FLIGHTS - BUT MAY NOT CONNECT TO OTHER AIRLINES
          WITH THE EXCEPTION OF DELTA CONNECTION/KLM AND
          AIR FRANCE.
TOUR CONDUCTOR DISCOUNTS             NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
          DISCOUNTS APPLY
AGENT DISCOUNTS    NO DISCOUNTS FOR SALE AGENTS.
ALL OTHER DISCOUNTS    NO DISCOUNTS FOR OTHERS.
MISCELLANEOUS PROVISIONS       NO PROVISIONS APPLY.
FARE BY RULE       NOT APPLICABLE.
GROUPS     NO GROUP PROVISIONS APPLY.
TOURS      NO TOUR PROVISIONS APPLY.
VISIT ANOTHER COUNTRY      NO VISIT ANOTHER COUNTRY PROVISIONS APPLY.
DEPOSITS       NO DEPOSIT PROVISIONS APPLY.
VOLUNTARY CHANGES      IN THE EVENT OF CHANGES TO TICKETED FLIGHTS
   BEFORE DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY AND WITHIN TICKET VALIDITY
   CERTAIN DOMESTIC REISSUE PROVISIONS MAY BE OVERRIDDEN
   BY THOSE OF DL INTERNATIONAL FARES
   NO CHARGE FOR REISSUE CHARGE HIGHEST FEE OF ALL
   CHANGED FARE COMPONENTS - CATEGORY 19 DISCOUNTS APPLY
   AND
     REPRICE USING FARES IN EFFECT TODAY
     PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
     1. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
     MUST BE DOMESTIC
     2. AF/DL/KL/VS FARES ARE USED
     3. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM REISSUE DATE TO
     DEPARTURE OF PRICING UNIT
     OR -
     REPRICE USING CURRENT FARES - ONLY BOOKING CODE
     CHANGES PERMITTED
     PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
     1. NO CHANGE TO FARE BREAKS
     2. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
     MUST BE DOMESTIC
     3. SAME TRAVEL DATES
     4. AF/DL/KL/VS FARES ARE USED
     5. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM REISSUE DATE TO
     DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY
   WHEN CHANGE RESULTS IN LOWER FARE SUBTRACT RESIDUAL
   FROM THE PENALTY THEN ADD-COLLECT/REFUND
   ENDORSEMENT BOX - HIGHER NON-REF AMT AND NEW
   ENDORSEMENTS.
   OR -
   AFTER DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY AND WITHIN TICKET VALIDITY
   CERTAIN DOMESTIC REISSUE PROVISIONS MAY BE OVERRIDDEN
   BY THOSE OF DL INTERNATIONAL FARES
   NO CHARGE FOR REISSUE CHARGE HIGHEST FEE OF ALL CHANGED
   FARE COMPONENTS - CATEGORY 19 DISCOUNTS APPLY AND
     REPRICE USING FARES IN EFFECT WHEN TKT WAS ISSUED
     PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
     1. NO CHANGE TO 1ST FARE COMPONENT
     2. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
     MUST BE DOMESTIC
     3. FULLY FLOWN FARE NOT REPRICED TO FURTHER POINT
     4. AF/AM/DL/KE/KL/VA/VS FARES ARE USED
     5. DL ANY FARE TYPE EXCEPT EOU/ERH/ERU/PRU ARE USED
     6. ALL RULE AND BOOKING CODE PROVISIONS ARE MET
     EXCEPT ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL
     7. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM ORIGINAL TKT DATE TO
     DEPARTURE OF PRICING UNIT
   REFUND VIA ORIGINAL FORM OF PAYMENT
   ENDORSEMENT BOX - HIGHER NON-REF AMT AND NEW
   ENDORSEMENTS.
.
VOLUNTARY REFUNDS      CHECK CATEGORY 16 OR CONTACT CARRIER FOR DETAILS.
NEGOTIATED FARES       NOT APPLICABLE.
INTERNATIONAL CONSTRUCTION     NOT A CONSTRUCTED FARE
```

Fun, uh?

The good news is that the fare is refundable (`CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED`) and changes are permitted (`CHANGES PERMITTED`), and there are no penalties or fees mentioned.

For comparison, other fares may say things such as `TICKET IS NON-REFUNDABLE IN CASE OF CANCEL`, `TICKET IS NON-REFUNDABLE IN CASE OF NO-SHOW`, `TICKETS MAY BE MANUALLY REFUNDED LESS 100.00USD CANCEL FEE`.

Note that if you decide to **change** rather than cancel your ticket, you will be charged the difference with the new fare, based on pricing **at the time of the change**.

Also note that one often needs to read the fare rules very carefully. It can quite often say one thing and its exact opposite, just within two different sets of conditions, exceptions or exclusions.

But Delta seems to be very much in "either it's not refundable or changeable at all or it can be refunded or exchanged for free" mode these days.

Answer (score 5):

https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/us/en/agent-resources/general-information/new-fare-basis-code-structure.html

This page explains how to find fare product and refundability from the fare basis code.

In the example here, where the code is QK6H40M2, the M in the next to last position says it's a main cabin product, and the H in the 4th position shows it's refundable.

Answer (score 3):

At booking, they should have you an option to show the rare rules and at this point it's always a good idea to display and save them. There may or may not be a away to display them again on the website, but many carriers do NOT make this easy and they are notoriously hard to read. Case in point, the fare rules for a recent Emirates itinerary was 751 pages !

Delta claims you should "contact reservations" https://www.delta.com/us/en/booking-information/fare-classes-and-tickets/ticket-rules-restrictions

This will NOT be easy: last few times I tried calling Delta the wait times exceeded 4 hours. You may be able to leave your number and they can call you back when you reach the top of the stack.

To make matters worse: If you want an authoritative answer, I would recommend calling at least 2 or 3 different agents. Or at least: if you don't like the first answer hang up and call a second time. More often than not, this works. Make sure you prep: ask for a written transcript or a link or written copy of the rules that the agent is referencing (or pretends to reference). Another good one: "Can you please point me to the documentation of my booking that states the specifics of this rule?"

Comment: You make it sound like it is a better use of time by showing up to an airport in person and going to the Delta desk in order to grill the customer service people.   But then I just had a vision that customer service desks have probably been replaced with banks of phones in order to connect you to their agents.